# How to solve this QCQP efficiently?

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, non-convex-optimization, qcqp

I'd like to solve the following quadratically constrained quadratic program (QCQP)

\begin{equation}\label{bijective}
    \begin{split}
      \min_{x} \quad &x^{T}Ax\\
      \mathrm{s.t.}\quad &c_k(x)\leq0,\quad k=1,2,\ldots,N
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

where $A$ is a sparse positive semidefinite matrix, $c_k(x)$ are *non-convex* quadratic functions with about 40000 variables. The Jacobian matrix $J=[\nabla c_1(x),\nabla c_2(x),\ldots,\nabla c_{N}(x)]$ is also sparse.

I use the MATLAB function `fmincon` to solve this problem and choose the `sqp` algorithm, but it is very slow and can't get a local minimum solution in a limited time.

How to solve the above problem efficiently? Is are any efficient software to do this?

Comment: Have you tried passing a subroutine for the Jacobian, stored as a MATLAB sparse matrix?

Comment: No, I don't utilize the sparse information, how to do? Could you give me any hint?

Comment: Are all the $c_k(x)$ convex quadratics? If so, the problem is a convex Quadratically Constrained Convex Program (QCQP), which is also can be expressed as a Second Order Cone Program (SOCP), for which there are specialized (interior) point algorithms.  If not all the  $c_k(x)$ are convex, you have a much more difficult non-convex problem.

Comment: Pablo Parrilo, Sanjay Lall, [Quadratically Constrained Quadratic Programming](http://www.mit.edu/~parrilo/cdc03_workshop/03_qcqp_2003_12_07_01_screen.pdf), 2003.

Comment: if $A \succ 0$ then use Cholesky decomposition on $A = LL^T$. the objective becomes $\min  \Vert Lx \Vert _2^2$ which is OMP if your constraints are norm bounds too, i think!!?

Comment: The constraint $c_k(x)$ is not convex.

Comment: Are you using user-supplied Hessian? That will include the contribution to the Hessian of the Lagrangian from the Hessians of the constraints, and should improve robustness, presuming you have enough memory to handle it. KNITRO has similar but higher quality algorithm implermentations; it can handle sparse Jacobian and Hessian